# Android - Load into SoundPool using variables.

Tags: android, soundpool

Currently I have four methods for loading different sounds into a SoundPool. I would like to simplify/shorten my code by having one universal method that takes an argument and loads different files based on that.

Currently, I have:

```
public void declareDrumsAmen(){
    kick = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.amenkick, 1);
    hat = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.amenhat, 1);
    snare = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.amensnare, 1);
    snare2 = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.amensnare2, 1);
}

public void declareDrumsFonk(){
    kick = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.fonkkick, 1);
    hat = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.fonkhat, 1);
    snare = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.fonksnare, 1);
    snare2 = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.fonksnare2, 1);
}
...
...
```

and two more. I would like to replace all of these with something along the lines of the following:

```
public void declareDrums(String kit){
    kick = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.kitkick, 1);
    hat = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.kithat, 1);
    snare = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.kitsnare, 1);
    snare2 = currentDrums.load(myContext, R.raw.kitsnare2, 1);
}
```

but I know no way of doing this. Can anyone offer some guidance?

Comment: Consider posting the solution you figured out as an _answer_. That will help future visitors know what the question was and what the solution was. ;-)

Comment: the site wouldn't let me! it probably will now, let me try. 

edit: done!

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, nevermind my stupidity. Figured it out, hopefully this will help someone else who stumbles upon this in a google search.

Method definition:

```
public void declareDrums(int resIDkick, int resIDhat, int resIDsnare, int resIDsnare2){
    kick = currentDrums.load(myContext, resIDkick, 1);
    hat = currentDrums.load(myContext, resIDhat, 1);
    snare = currentDrums.load(myContext, resIDsnare, 1);
    snare2 = currentDrums.load(myContext, resIDsnare2, 1);
}
```

Calling:

```
//declareDrums(R.raw.amenkick, R.raw.amenhat, R.raw.amensnare, R.raw.amensnare2);
declareDrums(R.raw.fpckick, R.raw.fpchat, R.raw.fpcsnare, R.raw.fpcsnare2);
```